# Truncated Explanatory Variable

Tags: regression, truncation, continuous-data

I am running a model where one of the explanatory variables is truncated. In particular, the variable measures the duration of unemployment (retrospectively) in months and it is truncated at 2 years, which happens for around 10% of the sample. In my model I want to treat the variable as continuous (as I already have quite a few categorical variables), but I am not sure how to deal with the truncated values - it seems that I have a continuous variable, which is also categorical at the same time (i.e. due to truncation).

The model will be something like: 
Y = A + B*X + C*Z + E, where Z<24
Y = A + B*X + C*24 +E, where Z>=24
where X includes some covariates and Z is the truncated variable of interest (continuous)

Issue: How to deal with Z in the regression?

Comment: You can simply use the truncated version of $Z$ as regressor since it is interval scaled. If you feel that such model structure does not represent reality well enough, you could think of adding a dummy variable (1 if $Z = 24$ and 0 otherwise) to represent the 10% truncated values.

Comment: An interesting article about censored regressors can be found on http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4542020?uid=3737760&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102954719551 with public version on http://web.mit.edu/tstoker/www/Rigobon_Stoker_IER_June_07.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The paper by Rigobon and Stoker that Michael M. cites in his second comment is very interesting but rather technical (incidentally, it recommends strongly against adding a dummy variable). But, while it makes some theoretical recommendations, it doesn't give any code and may be hard to implement. While I can see that it is cited by 98 other papers, I don't have a way to access those, but one of them might have code for the methods R and S recommend.

One idea, though, is to take a missing data approach and do multiple imputation based on the variables you do have. I think you would have to pick a model that doesn't impute any values below 24 months, but maybe you could do that by brute force.